# How should you disable a button from being ran over and over upon every click?

Tags: swift, segue

I don't know why but I was under the assumption that a button shouldn't be clickable over and over again to redo itself....

I have a fairly simple code.
When my button is clicked, it downloads an image using urlSession into the backgroundview of another viewController and segues into it.

My problem is that if click on button 3 times while I wait for the image to load, my viewController segues 3 layers down into a navigationController and to get back to the original viewController I have to click the back button 3 times. Shouldn't I not be able to segue 3 layers down!?

```
@IBAction func showImage(_: UIButton) {

    loadImage()
}
func loadImage () {
    let url = URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/1280px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            print("You got an error:\(error)")
            return
        }
        let img = UIImage(data: data )
        let imgview = UIImageView(image: img)
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let ivc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showImage")
        ivc.view = imgview
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ivc, animated: true)
    }
    session.resume()
}
```

Comment: Disable the button before you start loading the image?

Comment: @PhillipMills So my code isn't structured in a wrong way? Except that I just need to add that? And after I have segued I would enable button again?

Comment: @Honey have you even read the title of your question?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov yes...what about it? Is it funny or confusing? Edit if you please

Comment: @Honey It doesn't make sense

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov thanks for the feedback. I edited the title and the body a bit. Is it good now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Phillip Mills comment, this is what I have done:

I added a

```
@IBOutlet weak var showImage: UIButton!
```

and then upon clicking, I disabled the button with:

```
showImage.isEnabled = false
```

And after doing the segue I enabled it again with:

```
showImage.isEnabled = true
```

My full code is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var showImage: UIButton!  // Added
    @IBAction func showImage(_: UIButton) {
        showImage.isEnabled = false // Added
        loadImage()
    }
    func loadImage () {
        let url = URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/1280px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("You got an error:\(error)")
                return
            }
            let img = UIImage(data: data )
            let imgview = UIImageView(image: img)
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let ivc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showImage")
            ivc.view = imgview
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ivc, animated: true)
            self.showImage.isEnabled = true // Added


        }
        session.resume()
    }
```